# How to do sum of different columns which itself are repeated in BigQuery SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table with two columns and I want to have sum of the columns in BigQuery. The two columns itself are **RECORD** type and **REPEATED**. It has category, value pairs.

Below is the sample of table

```
|-----------|--------------|--------|-----------|--------|-------|
|   Date    |  A.category  |A.value |B.category | B.value|   id  |
|-----------|--------------|--------|-----------|--------|-------|
| 2019-01-20|     BC       |  1234  |           |        | af567 |
|-----------|--------------|--------|-----------|--------|-------|
| 2019-01-21|     CD       |  1234  |           |        | bh678 |      
|-----------|--------------|--------|-----------|--------|-------|
| 2019-01-22|              |        |   BC      | 3456   | af567 |      
|-----------|--------------|--------|-----------|--------|-------|
| 2019-01-23|              |        |   CD      | 3444   | bh678 |      
|-----------|--------------|--------|-----------|--------|-------|
```

The column A and B in the table are **ARRAYS** with category and value fields.

Note that the column B is empty before the date 2019-01-22 and column A is empty after that.

Now I want to have query that fill the column A after 2019-01-22 with the SUM of column A and column B values keeping the category same for column A as of B for particular id.

So basically if the date is less than 2019-01-22 keep the original values of column A and if the date is more than 2019-01-22 fill the column A with SUM of column A and B value for every row.

I want output like this

```
|-----------|--------------|--------|-----------|--------|-------|
|   Date    |  A.category  |A.value |B.category | B.value|   id  |
|-----------|--------------|--------|-----------|--------|-------|
| 2019-01-20|     BC       |  1234  |           |        | af567 |
|-----------|--------------|--------|-----------|--------|-------|
| 2019-01-21|     CD       |  1234  |           |        | bh678 |      
|-----------|--------------|--------|-----------|--------|-------|
| 2019-01-22|     BC       |  4690  |   BC      | 3456   | af567 |      
|-----------|--------------|--------|-----------|--------|-------|
| 2019-01-23|     CD       |  4678  |   CD      | 3444   | bh678 |      
|-----------|--------------|--------|-----------|--------|-------|
```

How do I achieve this using SQl in BigQuery?

Comment: data sample you presented is oversimplified and not really presents fact that A and B are repeated. because of this it is still not clear what logic you have in mind - please make your input and expected output examples better

Comment: Can you please elaborate on why are you trying to perform this in a single query? this will be slow and inneficient. Spliting this in 3 tables (a values, b values, merged values) will be a better approach.